# Passing values to web service - Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, http-post

I am trying to pass signup details in our app 
the stucture of service is

```
   FirstName: '',
        MiddleName: '',
        LastName: '',
        EmailAddress: '',
        ReceiveUpdates: false,
        Login: {
            UserName: '',
            Password: '',
        }
```

Code behind my signup button is

```
     AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
               RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                params.put("FirstName", "ALi");
                params.put("MiddleName", "Farhan");
                params.put("LastName", "Ali");
                params.put("EmailAddress", "far67890@gmail.com");
                params.put("ReceiveUpdates", "false");
                params.put("UserName", "farhan6");
                params.put("Password", "cricket");

                        client.post("http://urb-app.com/Buyer/Register", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                                super.onSuccess(s);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success :" + s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //  tv.append("service_ReloadSqlDB" + "    " + s);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                                super.onFailure(throwable);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Response for onFailure ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
```

I am using AsyncHttpClient for posting request, The problem is how can i pass username and password inside login body

```
 Login: {
            UserName: '',
            Password: '',
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating your request params in a HashMap. You can make something like `HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();`
and inside you can put another HashMap with your login details.

```
HashMap<String, String> login = new HashMap<>();
login.put("username", "farhan6");
login.put("password", "cricket");
```

and now you can put this in the first params like

```
params.put("Login",login);
```

From this you can create a RequestParams object like

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams(paramMap);
```

You can see more help [here](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

Comment: Thanks alot it seems like it should work but there is a problem, I cant pass hashmap to a RequestParams. It says cant convert hashmap to string.

Comment: Sorry my bad, error resolved i missed out the type in initialization of hashmap. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks alot but there is a slight problem i cant pass hashmap String object to requestparams.

Comment: @farhan678 what's the problem that you are facing now? Update your question with the error.

Comment: I figured that out. there was a problem with my HTTP request. Async HTTP was problematic, I am now using HTTPurlconnection. Its perfectly working now. Thanks for your help :)